# How to protect a Rails model attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

My Invoice model has an address_id attribute, and I don't want this address_id to change FOREVER. So I don't want this to happen outside the class:

```
invoice.address_id = 1
invoice.address = some_address
```

Rails automatically adds this address_id attribute to the model from the invoice table, so how can I declare this attribute private/protected? Calling

```
attr_protected :address_id
```

is most likely not the solution since based on the documentation it only prevents mass assignments.

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You want [`attr_readonly`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001317).

Comment: Wouldn't this deter Rails from updating and saving the Model back to the DB?

Comment: nice - didn't know the method existed ;)
@Gishu no i don't think it would block saving model - it would just ignore changes to the fields listed in *attributes

Comment: Is this method only available in Rails 2.*? I am running in Rails 1.2.6.

Comment: Not sure.  Look it up.  Add it in if it isn't.  :)

Answer (score 5):

Not as pretty as a one liner, but code below should work (and you could always do some metaprogramming to write an 'immutable' method)

```
def address_id=(id)
  if new_record?
    write_attribute(:address_id, id)
  else
    raise 'address is immutable!'
  end
end
```